# Float multiplication differs from integer division

Tags: floating-point

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");

    int64_t res1 = INT32_MAX * 0.1f;
    int64_t res2 = INT32_MAX / 10;
    
    std::cout << "res1: " << res1 <<"\n";
    std::cout << "res2: " << res2 <<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

> Hello World
>  res1: 214748368
>  res2: 214748364

Simple question: Why the results differ?

Tested with onlinegdb.com

Comment: Try `INT32_MAX * 0.1;`  (no `f`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In common C++ implementations, `float` uses the IEEE-754 32-bit binary format. This format represents numbers as a sign, a 24-bit integer, and a scaling by a power of two. The source text `0.1f` is converted to the nearest representable value, which is +13,421,773•2<sup>−27</sup> = 0.100000001490116119384765625. They then perform the `*`, the `INT32_MAX` operand, 2,147,483,647, is also converted to `float`. The nearest representable value is +1•2<sup>31</sup> = 2,148,483,648. When these are multiplied, the result is +13,421,773•2<sup>4</sup> = 214,748,368.

In contrast `INT32_MAX / 10` divides 2,147,483,647 by 10 and truncates, yielding 214,748,364.